# Implementing Hough Transform for Lines

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to implement Hough Transform for line detection in an already pre-processed image.
So my input image is a black-white edge image, 0 - background and 255 - foreground. I do not wish to use the inbuilt HoughLines library by OpenCV. 
I am actually stuck with creating the accumulator and increasing its values properly. I cant figure out where i went wrong, so here is my code block :

```
int diagonal = sqrt(height * height + width * width);

IplImage *acc = cvCreateImage (cvSize(180, 2 * diagonal),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
unsigned char* accData = (unsigned char *)acc->imageData;

for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<step; j++)
    {
        if (data[i*step + j] > 200)
        {
            for (int theta=0; theta<180; theta++)
            {
                int p = j * cos(theta) + i * sin(theta);
                if (p > 0)
                    accData[theta*180 + p] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output image that i get in acc is not what it should look like. I am not getting any sinusoids, instead only white patches here and there. Can anyone provide any feedback about where i went wrong ?

Comment: *"I do not wish to use the inbuilt HoughLines library by OpenCV"* - out of interest, why not?

Comment: cos and sin expect input in radians, not degrees

Comment: I use something [alike](https://sourceforge.net/p/fitsviewhartman/code/ci/tip/tree/src/NOCUDA.c#l69), but it works well. To make it more quickly first you should fill array of sin/cos (and as said @moonshadow, your error is in argument).

Comment: Yes the parameter changing worked. The result is still not accurate though - i am getting a vertically stretched image but it fills the purpose for now. And yes i will be using the inbuilt function later on for final use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see there is that you don t use sinus with radians values but with degree values you could change it as follows:

```
int p = j * cos((double)theta*PI/180) + i * sin((double)theta*PI/180);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. the results now are a lot more like it should be. I will continue the process to get the exact co-ordinates.